# Clear Orchard CMS Database Cache

Tags: orchardcms

I want to manipulate data directly into database.
But the changes not reflected in Orchard Website.
How can tell to Orchard clear all database cache after making some data changes in database?

Comment: I recommend describing more specifically what you are trying to change and what you want the outcome to be. Maybe somebody could give you a suggestion that didn't require direct database manipulation.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are adding records to the table LayerPartRecord? This won't work because layers are content items in Orchard, they are built from more tables than just the layerpartrecord table. You will have to add records to several other tables. It begs the question, why are you trying to do this? Orchard does not lend itself to direct database modification. Sebastien Ros talks a little about Orchards database structure here, if you really have your heart set on modifying the database: http://sebastienros.com/understanding-orchard-s-database, but I'd definitely say it is more trouble than it is worth.

Instead you can create layers using the Orchard command line:

```
layer create Authenticated /LayerRule:"authenticated" /Description:"The widgets in this layer are displayed when the user is authenticated"
```

Or use the Import/Export module, so your import code will look something like this:

```
<Layer Id="/Layer.LayerName=Authenticated" Status="Published">
  <CommonPart Owner="/User.UserName=admin" CreatedUtc="2014-07-01T12:22:26Z" PublishedUtc="2014-07-01T12:22:26Z" ModifiedUtc="2014-07-01T12:22:26Z"/>
  <LayerPart Name="Authenticated" Description="The widgets in this layer are displayed when the user is authenticated" LayerRule="authenticated"/>
</Layer>
```

Comment: Thank Hazza, i need to manipulate data from database, because of lots of changes should be done. I realized for adding a layer to Orachard from DB, except of Widget_LayerPartRecods, need to update Framework_ContentItemRecord, Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord tables too. But your answer was very useful for me. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can disable `SysCache` module, then Orchard won't cache database output. Otherwise you can just restart your website, that will also clear database cache.

Also make sure changes you make to the database are saved there. For example WebMatrix won't save row until you fully deselect it.

Comment: SysCache was disabled. when i add some widget layers to database from SSMS, new widget layers not appears  in Orchard control panel. Why?